# How to draw the following figure using PGF-Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

**I want to draw the following graph using PGF-Tikz**:

[image]

**Using the following codes:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    
    \begin{axis}[mystyle/.style={semithick},        
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        xtick={0,1,2,4,8},
        extra y ticks={3.5},
        extra y tick labels={$\nu_p(\alpha)$},
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={$\nu_2(a_n)$},
        xlabel style={right},
        ylabel style={above},
        x tick label style={anchor=north,below,yshift=0.5ex},
        yticklabel style={red},
        extra y tick style={yticklabel style={color={black}}},
        xmin=-1,
        xmax=10,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=4.5]
        % Main lines
        \addplot[mystyle,green,thick]coordinates{(0,3.5)(1,0.5)(2,0)};
        \addplot[mystyle,orange,thick]coordinates{(2,0)(4,0)};
        \addplot[mystyle,thick]coordinates{(4,0)(8,2)};
        % vertical dashed lines
        \addplot[mystyle,dashed]coordinates{(8,2)(8,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**I got the following picture-**

[image]

I don't know how to remove the the numbers on vertical axis, i.e., I want to remove the labels or numbers `-2,2,4,-4` on vertical axis.

I also want to increase gaps between the numbers on horizontal axis.

Kindly help.

Please make correction of my code.

**Edit:**  The following code of @Ronald produce the following graph:
[image]

But I want to delete the `horizontal cut` on the vertical axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    
    \begin{axis}[mystyle/.style={semithick},        
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        xtick={0,1,2,4,8},
        extra x ticks={0,0}, %adds tick
        extra x tick style={ xticklabel style={below right}}, %moves 0 a little to the right so it does not collide the y axis.
        extra y ticks={3.5},
        extra y tick labels={$\nu_p(\alpha)$},
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={$\nu_2(a_n)$},
        xlabel style={right},
        ylabel style={above},
        x tick label style={anchor=north,below,yshift=0.5ex},
        yticklabels={,,} %this here I changed
        extra y tick style={yticklabel style={color={black}}},
        xmin=-1,
        xmax=10,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=4.5]
        % Main lines
        \addplot[mystyle,green,thick]coordinates{(0,3.5)(1,0.5)(2,0)};
        \addplot[mystyle,orange,thick]coordinates{(2,0)(4,0)};
        \addplot[mystyle,thick]coordinates{(4,0)(8,2)};
        % vertical dashed lines
        \addplot[mystyle,dashed]coordinates{(8,2)(8,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how to delete the `horizontal-cut` on the  vertical axis at those 4 points ?

Comment: Hello! I edited the answer. You have to add `\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}}`

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved the problem. One final request- How to add the number `0` on the horizontal axis

Comment: Add `\extra x ticks={0,0},` see edit

Answer (score 3):

Ticks on y-axis you can remove by `ytick=\empty`. In MWE below is also removed all clutter in your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} % <---


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    axis lines=center, % <---
    xtick={1,2,4,8},
    extra x ticks={0},  % <---
    ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\footnotesize}, % <---    
    ytick=\empty, % <--- remove yticks
    extra y ticks={3.5},
    extra y tick labels={$\nu_p(\alpha)$},
    xlabel={$n$},
    ylabel={$\nu_2(a_n)$},
    xlabel style={right},
    ylabel style={above},
    xmin=-1,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-4.5,
    ymax=4.5,
    every axis plot post/.append style={thick}% thickness of plotted lines
    ]
    % Main lines
\addplot[green]  coordinates {(0,3.5)(1,0.5)(2,0)};
\addplot[orange] coordinates {(2,0)(4,0)};
\addplot[black]  coordinates {(4,0)(8,2)};
% vertical dashed lines
\draw[dashed] (8,2) -- (8,0);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
added x tick label at zero point, as OP asked in his comment.

Comment: thanks. How to add `0` on the horizontal axis in the same level ?

Comment: with `extra x tick`. I will add this asap.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, see edited answer.